# select multiple items in asp.net listbox from code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two databound listboxes. The first only shows items that have been assigned to my product. The second listbox shows all available items. What I want to do is select all of the items in listbox 2 that list box one contains.

For example:
ListBox1-
Item 1
Item 3
ListBox2-
Item 1 (Selected)
Item 2
Item 3 (Selected)

Code I have:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            foreach(ListItem f in ListBoxSourceDetail.Items)
            {
                myList.Add(f.Value);
            }
            myList.ForEach(delegate(string n)
            {
                ListBoxSourceEdit.SelectedValue = n;
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, I was over thinking it... Loop through each list item in the first box and then find each matching result in the second table to be selected.

```
foreach(ListItem i in ListBoxSourceDetail.Items)
        {
            ListBoxSourceEdit.Items.FindByText(i.ToString()).Selected = true;

        }
```

Comment: You probably should be finding by value not text. Typically the value is unique where that isn't necessarily the case with the text.

Comment: @Adam Spicer, I agree, but in this case it is ok because the items come from a table that won't allow duplicate values.